# Laravel4: load relations into unsaved new model instance?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm looking for the way to load relations into a model instance, which has been just created.

For example, I have a ServiceOrder model, which has three `belongsTo` relations. I want to allow user to create it. During creation he selects values of these relations. On selection, many properties of related models are loaded into the view dynamically, not just id.

If user makes a mistake, I need to redirect him back to creation screen with errors marked. My view renders ServiceOrder model using relation properties as if they were loaded. Here is the example of one field:

```html
{{ ExtForm::groupOpen('symptom_id') }}
    <label for="symptom_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Неисправность</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name="symptom_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Неисправность" data-provide="selectize-select" data-autocomplete-url="{{ route('api.symptoms') }}/" data-autocomplete-url-init data-title-parts="cat3_name" data-render-options-template="#symptom_options_template">
            @if($model->device->id) <option value="{{ $model->symptom->id }}" data-data="{{ e($model->symptom->toJson()) }}" selected>{{ $model->symptom->cat3_name }}</option> @endif
        </select>
       {{ ExtForm::errors() }}
       <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ route('symptom.index', ['select' => true]) }} " data-selectize-control-name = "device_id">Выбрать неисправность</a>
    </div>
{{ ExtForm::groupClose() }}
```

Currently my solution is as follows. I wrote a small helper:

```php
class RelatedModelHelper {

    /**
     * @param \Eloquent $model
     * @param array     $relations Names of classes of related models
     */
    public static function fillRelationsFromInput (\Eloquent $model, array $relations) {
        foreach ($relations as $relatedModelClass) {
            $funcName = \Str::snake($relatedModelClass);
            $key      = $funcName . '_id';

            /** @var BelongsTo $belongsTo */
            $belongsTo = $model->{$funcName}();
            if (\Input::old($key)) {
                /** @var \Eloquent $relatedModel */
                $relatedModel = $relatedModelClass::findOrFail(\Input::old($key));
            } else {
                $relatedModel = new $relatedModelClass;
            }
            $belongsTo->associate($relatedModel);
        }
    }
}
```

And now preload all relations (if any) in the controller like this:

```php
public function getCreate () {

    $model              = new ServiceOrder();

    RelatedModelHelper::fillRelationsFromInput($model, [
        Device::class,
        Symptom::class,
        Customer::class
    ]);
    return View::make('service_order.create')->with('model', $model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows:

As long is your foreign keys on the model are set, relations will be autoloaded:

```
public function getCreate () {

    $model              = new ServiceOrder();

    $model->customer_id = 1;
    $model->symptom_id  = 1;
    $model->device_id   = 1;

    return View::make('service_order.create')->with('model', $model);
}
```

And you just need to handle the case, where empty objects need to be created.